# Kill command on outlook invokes Microsoft error reporting Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, kill

I am actually trying to close some processes using kill command. 
All the processes are getting killed graciously but when I invoke kill command on Microsoft Outlook like

```
kill PID
```

it's getting killed(expected) and also it opens up the Microsoft Error Reporting. 
[image: Mircrosoft Error Reporting Dialog box]
How to kill a process like an outlook as if I went to File->Quit Outlook?

Comment: Using linux, or unix, or macos? Looks like just macos right?

Comment: You might try `kill -9 PID`.  This means the kernel will kill the process without prejudice.  I'm not sure but I suspect the error reporting won't get a chance to get control.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft error reporting (MERP) can be disabled as follows :

- Quit all Microsoft apps
- Go to */HD/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/MERP2.0*
- Launch *Microsoft Error Reporting.app*
- Go to *Microsoft Error Reporting* in the Menu Bar
- Select *Preferences*
- Clear the check box
- Quit MERP

This isn't really recommended when the problem is not too annoying.

When there are no problems with the operation of the system/software,
MERP running in the background should not be an issue.

In case of a real problem, the information it provides can be useful in correcting it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Here, why the MERP pops up when I quit through kill command and not when I click quit in my mac? 
Is it an abnormal termination?

Comment: Yes, MERP detected it as an Outlook crash. I agree that this is not very smart of it.

Comment: I have also been noticing,  CrashServiceHelper of their respective apps is called on calling kill.